# How to fix get method that selects customer orders grouped by postcode in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to call my endpoint that should return a grouped result based on Getting orders grouped by postcode filtered in descending order by Total. Total is the number of orders for each of the postcodes.

The database structure is:
Customers, Orders, Servers and there's a one to many link between customer and orders e.g. one customer can have many orders.

My current code returns error:

> **System.NullReferenceException**: **'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

Here is my c# code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all orders grouped by postcode.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The orders.</returns>
[HttpGet("ByPostcode")]
public IActionResult ByPostcode()
{
    //Filter orders.
    var orders = _context.Orders.Include(order => order.Customer).ToList();

    //Group by postcode. 
    //Descending list of postcodes and total number of orders for each of those postcodes.
    var groupedResult = orders.GroupBy(order => order.Customer.PostCode)
        .ToList()
        .Select(group => new
        {
            PostCode = group.Key,
            Total = group.Sum(x => x.Total)
        }).OrderByDescending(result => result.Total)
        .ToList();

    return Ok(groupedResult);
}
```

The expected result should be a list of orders grouped by postcode with the total of orders for the postcode for example:

```
[
  {
    "postcode": "A",
    "total": 10
  },
  {
    "postcode": "AWE",
    "total": 23423
  },
  {
    "postcode": "TRR",
    "total": 453
  },
]
```

The actual result is:
**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**.

MyProject.Models.Order.Customer.get returned null.

[image: Customers table]

[image: Orders table]

Comment: do you have data in database?

Comment: looks like you dont have proper data in your database for the filter that you put.

Comment: The error says that you don't have Customer for at least one Order in your DB

Comment: I think that an `order` doesn't have a `.Customer`. So check your `orders` variable

Comment: There's data in the database.@SmartestVEGA

Comment: I've added screenshots of the customer and order tables in the database.

Comment: Do you have constraints set? If the error is caused by what you mentioned, one (or more) of the 'Orders' points to non-existing 'Customers'. By running a query like SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Customers) you can find out which.

Comment: No but see my answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was because I had orders with customerId being NULL and Total being 0 and I wasn't handling it. Fixed now.